# Can't add target Android version for Android Project in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I just had this happen to me while importing a project from existing code and I didn't see the answer here.  I hope someone finds this helpful.

I was getting '...cannot be resolved...' errors as if I was missing the Android SDK even though I had it installed.  Lots of them pertained to 'android.*' imports.  Adding the .jar files to the build path did not resolve the issue either.

I then went to 'MY_PROJECT' > Properties > Android and found that Eclipse ignored me when I selected a target version and clicked 'Apply'.  There were no errors, but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**: my project.properties file was set to 'readonly'.  I removed the readonly flag (right click on project.properties in Eclipse > Properties > Resource, you could probably do it in your file system as well).  Then I went to 'MY_PROJECT' > Properties > Android and selected the Android build target and my project.properties file was updated!